# AngularJS transcluded scope form element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-transclude

I am having an issue in Angular being able to get a reference to a form element from sibling transclude elements.

HTML

```
<div modal-panel>
    <modal-content>
        <form name="myForm">
            [...]
        </form>
    </modal-content>
    <modal-buttons>
        <button ng-click="foo()" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Go</button>
    </modal-buttons>
</div>
```

Directive

```
function ModalPanelDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            [...]
        },
        transclude: {
            buttons: "?modalButtons",
            content: "modalContent"
        },
        link: function (scope,el,attr,ctrl,$transclude) {
            [...]
        },
        templateUrl: 'modal-panel.html'
    };
}
```

My issue is that the `ng-disabled` directive on the button is unable to access the `myForm` variable for the form element that is defined in the sibling transclude and therefore is not being disabled when the form is invalid.

How can I get a reference to the form variable in the `modal-content` section that I can use in the `modal-buttons` section of my transclude?

Please bear in bind that this modal directive is used in other areas of my app that do not have forms present.